# self sizing UITableViewCell goes small

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a table view cell prototype (similar to one below) programmatically.

[image]

The designed the cell with two stack views, 
a) a **vertical stack view** to contain the text labels and, 
b) a **horizontal stack view** to contain the image view & vertical stack view

I create the required views, stuff it in stack view, and pin stack view to table cell's contentView in the init() of tableviewcell.

And from cellForItemAtIndexPath I call configureCell() to populate data of the cell.

My init() looks like this

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    textStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [priorityNameLabel, descriptionLabel])
    textStackView.axis = .vertical
    textStackView.alignment = .leading
    textStackView.distribution = .fill
    textStackView.spacing = 5

    containerStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [priorityImageView, textStackView])
    containerStackView.axis = .horizontal
    containerStackView.alignment = .center
    containerStackView.spacing = 5
    containerStackView.distribution = .fill

    contentView.addSubview(containerStackView)
    containerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pinContainerToSuperview()
}

func pinContainerToSuperview() {
    containerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).activate()
    containerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).activate()
    containerStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).activate()
    containerStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).activate()
}
```

In my view controller, I set tableView rowHeight to automaticDimension and estimated height to some approx. value. When I run the code, all I'm getting is,

[image]

The narrow horizontal lines on the top of the image are my tableview cells (My data count is 3 in this case). I couldn't figure out the problem. Can someone point out what's going wrong here?

**EDIT 1:**

These are the instance members of my TableViewCell class

```
var containerStackView: UIStackView!
var textStackView: UIStackView!

var priorityImageView: UIImageView! {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return imageView
}

var priorityNameLabel: UILabel! {
    let label = UILabel()
    return label
}

var descriptionLabel: UILabel! {
    let label = UILabel()
    return label
}
```

Comment: I cannot see in your code where and how you create the labels and image view - can you add that part please?

Comment: You have not given any minimum height to label/multiline text/image/stack views. That is why cell doesn't get any height and shrinks. You can set >= height constraint through storyboard/code to solve the issue.

Comment: If the cell is just three view objects, why do you need to put them into a stack?

Comment: @Losiowaty added the instance members of table cell.

Comment: @slickdaddy I chose stackView in order reduce the number of constraints required for the design.

Comment: You have 3 objects which should equate to 11 constraints. Why do you want to reduce the number of constraints? A well-constructed UI is rich with constraints. And a stack view itself uses constraints. I would recommend simplifying this cell by getting rid of the stack view and using auto layout to give you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your labels and image view as computed properties - this means that every time you access them **a new instance is created**. This is bad. This basically means that when you set them as arranged subvies of your stack views and then try to configure them later, you work on different objects.

Simplest solution would be to create your labels and image view the way you create your stack views in init.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!! It made sense as well. How about lazy properties? say I do, lazy var lbl: UILabel = { return UILabel() }. Does this also create UILabel instance every time I access it?

Comment: No, lazy would work here, there just is no need for it. In general lazy should be used for properties that are expensive to create and not so likely to be used. As always - more in the docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html